# Create fresh bash shell from .sh script

Tags: bash

As the last command of my `decrypt.sh` script, I wish for it to create a fresh shell in the newly created folder with `unset HISTFILE`.

At this point the user should be able to interact with this new shell.

In this folder will be an `encrypt.sh` script, which the user can run. As its last action it must delete the folder and exit out of this shell, returning the user to the original shell.

How can I accomplish this?

While a bash solution would be useful for me, a generic solution may be useful for someone else (but maybe impossible?).

Comment: If your question “How do I make a shell script become interactive when it finishes?”?

Answer (score 3):

The `decrypt.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create working directory.
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

# Remove the temporary directory upon exiting
trap 'rm -r "$tmpdir"' EXIT

# Copy "encrypt.sh" from somewhere.
cp /somewhere/encrypt.sh "$tmpdir"

# Start an interactive shell in the directory with
# HISTFILE set to /dev/null
( cd "$tmpdir" && HISTFILE=/dev/null bash )
```

The `encrypt.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# When exiting, terminate the parent shell
trap 'kill -s HUP "$PPID"' EXIT

# rest of script goes here
```

The `decrypt.sh` scrip takes care of setting up the working directory and deleting it. Setting the directory up involves creating it (using `mktemp -d` to create a temporary directory), and copying the `encrypt.sh` script into it from wherever the original may be located.  Deleting the working directory happens when the `decrypt.sh` script terminates.

The `encrypt.sh` script will terminate its parent shell when it itself exits by sending it the `HUP` signal, prompting the `decrypt.sh` script to remove the working directory.  The directory will also be deleted if the user exits the interactive shell without running `encrypt.sh`.

---

Instead of setting `HISTFILE` to `/dev/null` or trying to *unset* it in the created interactive shell, you could just set `HOME` to the temporary directory.  The history file will be created under `$HOME` and will be deleted together with the directory when `decrypt.sh` exits:

```
( cd "$tmpdir" && HOME="$tmpdir" bash )
```

Note that this affects the behaviour of tilde expansion and of `cd` with no argument and anything else that may be using the `HOME` variable.

A less invasive variation is to set the `HISTFILE` variable explicitly to a filename under the temporary directory:

```
( cd "$tmpdir" && HISTFILE="$tmpdir/.bash_history" bash )
```

---

Slightly related: A tool that uses some of these things (creates an interactive shell in a temporary working directory in a clean environment, with clean-up when the shell exits):

- https://github.com/kusalananda/shell-toolbox

Disclaimer: I wrote that.

Comment: Can I make the new bash inherit its environment from the old one? Do I have to somehow execute `~/.bash_profile`? This creates an additional complication: My `~/.bash_profile` contains `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups:ignorespace;  shopt -s histappend`. If I could pass a `DISABLE_HIST` flag _into_ `~/.bash_profile`, I could put those statements inside an `if` block, maybe?

Comment: @Pi Environment variables would always be inherited, so you make `DISABLE_HIST` an environment variable by exporting it, it would be inherited by the new shell. You could also set it on the new shell's command line: `DISABLE_HIST=yes bash`.